# Error Upload image in Asp.net core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am new to Asp.net core,i would like to upload image.I have been following this video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fx-EQ1hT8R0). While I was running the application, the program automatically shut down when I choose image and click submit. I don't understand where the error arises.

This is Html page:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
        <input type="file" name="uploadfiles" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </p>
</form>
```

This is IndexModel pages:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly Razorpages_FileUploadContext _context;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

        public IndexModel(Razorpages_FileUploadContext context, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            _context = context;
            _environment = environment;
        }

        public IList<ImageSave> ImageSave { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            ImageSave = await _context.ImageSave.ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IFormFile uploadfiles, ImageSave img)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            string imgext = Path.GetExtension(uploadfiles.FileName);
            if (imgext == ".jpg" || imgext == ".png" || imgext == ".gif")
            {
                var imgsave = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "Images", uploadfiles.FileName);
                var stream = new FileStream(imgsave, FileMode.Create);
                await uploadfiles.CopyToAsync(stream);
                stream.Close();
                img.Imgname = uploadfiles.FileName;
                img.Imgpath = imgsave;
                await _context.ImageSave.AddAsync(img);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
```

I upload image and submit,the program shut down,Error message in cmd: D:\c_sharp\LearnRazorPages\Razorpages_FileUpload\Razorpages_FileUpload\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Razorpages_FileUpload.exe (process 12992) exited with code -1. To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.

Could you help me,please!

Comment: What do you mean by the program automatically shut down? Any error message?

Comment: I upload image and submit,the program shut down,Error message in cmd:
D:\c_sharp\LearnRazorPages\Razorpages_FileUpload\Razorpages_FileUpload\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Razorpages_FileUpload.exe (process 12992) exited with code -1.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.

Comment: Did vscode or visual studio close? Try cleaning your solution `dotnet clean` or read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-clean for a complete workthrough on how to achieve that and see if that helps

Comment: The program has errors in visual studio 2019.But it don't error in visual studio 2019 Preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, the code you post works well for me.
[image]

The main reason of crashing is about your VS `Debugging` setting.
Follow these steps in gif to turn off `Automatically close the console when debugging stops.`

[image]

Then, you might get errors about your codes with closing application.

Comment: thank you, i fixed it because my visual studio 2019 is error ,i repair it and my project is work well